# Starting with WPF - General questions

Tags: wpf, templates, radio-button

I am starting to learn WPF now and I am starting to use Blend as well, so I have some beginner questions:

1 - I wanted to know the difference between the "Simple" controls and regular controls, for example the difference between a SimpleButton and a Button.

2 - I want to make my own RadioButton, but since the functions will be the same and I am just changing it's appearance, I guess I just need to make a new template to a RadioButton right?

3 - The RadioButton I am creating is a grey square, with black text inside and a black bullet for the RadioButton selection indication. I think I just need to change the RadioButtons backcolor, but I cant find that option in Blend. Where is it?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

1- you refer to simple styles ? 
2- yes you are right
3- in the original template the 'dot' is set by visibility you can do the same for background

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
     <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Dot" Value="Visible"/>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: 1 - I still don't know what "simple styles" are, maybe I am, I don't know... what are them anyway?

3 - There is no option for the background for the ContentPresenter...should I be looking for something else?

4 - What is a Setter?

thanks!

Comment: 1. in blend "Simple button" for example is a simple style of a button and not a diffarent control ,3.show your code , i cant help you without it , 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx

Comment: I dont have a code yet...I am still learning. I wanted to do it all by using blend's graphical interface, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

1 - I didn't get you, what you mean by simple control, let me know more details

2- Yes you need to create a  control template for the Radio button, it will edit           the logical tree, and changes the appearance.

3 - If you really want to change the back color of the radio button, go to the control template you have created and apply the background property of the radiobutton.

Comment: Don't worry, this was a question back in 2012, right now I am pretty experienced with WPF. But just to be clear, I found some "simple button", "simple radio button " templates on Blend, they are very different than the ones that come with the framework, and they don't appear to be" simple", so I wanted to know what's their purpose, because I didn't like them at all, but they are all there, and you can find them on Microsofts website as the example on templates, and what I expected to see was the templates of the regular controls that come with the framework.

Comment: See the answer below, it speaks of blend simple styles.